# How Do I Get a List of All My Facebook Page IDs, Then Delete Them?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This is for a page I have the admin rights to. I'm trying to figure out a way to get a list of all of the post IDs and then run a query that deletes them? Basically, I want to purge all of the posts I've ever made on this page without having to do it one by one...because that will take forever.

Is this possible? What's the easiest way? I think there must be a way to use the graph api to grab the IDs and then run the DEL command

Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 1):

If all posts were made by one application then you can run a loop through `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts` and call HTTP DELETE on each post

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

> You can delete a post as long as your application created the post. You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID object with publish_stream permission.

So if all posts were not made by an application, this is not possible.